# Extract values between two text lines with spaces

Tags: python

I have multiple text files similar to the one shown below and need to extract the values between "Text1" and "Text2".

```
Name 



Text1




0 5
1 10
2 8
3 9
4 12
5 16
6 11
7 17
8 15
9 25


Text2    `
```

I wrote the following script, and it works fine:

```
import os
import csv
import numpy as np
data=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Path/to/file"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            lines = open(os.path.join(root,file)).readlines()
            for num, line in enumerate(lines):
                if "Name" in line:
                    Name=lines[num].split()[0]
                if "Text1" in line:
                    num_line_min=int(num+5)
                if "Text2" in line:
                    num_line_max=int(num-3)
                P1=[]
                D1=[]
                for i in range(10,19):
                    L1_2=lines[i]
                    L1_1=L1_2.split()
                    L2=float(L1_1[0])
                    D2=float(L1_1[1])
                    P1.append(L2)
                    D1.append(D2)
                P=np.array(P1)
                D=np.array(D1)
            datal=[Name,P,D]
            data.append(datal)
with open("Test.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

However, the line range in the above script (range(10,19) is not known upfront. So, I wrote the following script:

```
import os
import csv
import numpy as np
data=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Path/to/file"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            lines = open(os.path.join(root,file)).readlines()
            strings=open(os.path.join(root,file)).read()
            for num, line in enumerate(lines):
                Name=lines[1]
                if "Text1" in line:
                    num_line_min=int(num+5)
                if "Text2" in line:
                    num_line_max=int(num-3)
                P1=[]
                D1=[]
                for i in range(num_line_min,num_line_max):
                    L1_2=lines[i]
                    L1_1=L1_2.split()
                    L2=float(L1_1[0])
                    D2=float(L1_1[1])
                    P1.append(L2)
                    D1.append(D2)
                P=np.array(P1)
                D=np.array(D1)
            datal=[Name,P,D]
            data.append(datal)
with open("Test.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

It gives me the following error: NameError: name 'num_line_min' is not defined, even though num_line_min is defined after the first script has run.

Could anyone help me to fix the second script?
Thanks.

Comment: `num_line_min` is only defined when "Text1" is seen for the first time.  That text is not present in the very first line of the file, so when the statement `for i in range(num_line_min,num_line_max)` tries to run, the error happens.  Did you really intend that loop to run for **every** line of the file?  Seems to me you would want to wait until both "Text1" and "Text2" have been seen in the file...

Comment: If you thought hard-coding `(10,19)` was bad, then why keep the offsets of `+5` and `-3` hard-coded?

Comment: @blhsing, in my text files, the lines I'm interested in are always +5 and -3 lines away from "Text1" and "Text2", respectively.

Comment: Why is `strings=open(os.path.join(root,file)).read()` there? You don't use `strings`.

Comment: That's a strange CSV. Each row includes the string representation of two numpy arrays. Is that really the goal?

Comment: You went from `if "Name" in line: Name=lines[num].split()[0]` to `Name=lines[1]`. Any reason for that change?

Comment: @tdelaney The text file and the script in my question are simplified examples of what I actually have. There is a conditional statement in the actual script, which extracts "Name"="NG" when a specific text is not in the text file. That is why "strings=open(..." is in the script in my question. Please see my comments below regarding the strange csv file. I should have better cleaned up the example script and explained the situation in my question to avoid these comments :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import csv, os
import numpy as np


def worker(file):
    with open(file, "r") as READ:
        name, collect = file, False
        P, D = [], []
        for line in READ:
            if "Text2" in line: break
            elif "Text1" in line: collect = True
            elif "Name" in line: name = line.strip()
            elif line.strip() and collect: # continue only if line is not blank
                try: L2, D2 = list(map(float, line.split()))
                except ValueError: continue # continue loop if line is not two floats
                P.append(L2)
                D.append(D2)
    return name, np.array(P), np.array(D)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # list comprehension to create list of files
    files = [
        os.path.join(root, file)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r".")
        for file in files if file.endswith(".txt")
        ]
    
    # create multiple worker threads and write results
    with open("TEST.CSV", "w", newline="") as WRITE, ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        writer = csv.writer(WRITE)
        for result in pool.map(worker, files):
            writer.writerow(result)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your script works, but it grabs all numbers from the entire text file, while I only need those in the lines between "Text1" and "Text2". My actual files are several thousand lines long, with the lines containing text and numbers. How can your script be revised to extract only the numbers between "Text1" and "Text2"?

Comment: updated my answer to only start collecting only if "Text1" has been parsed.  simple test with the new code at [https://onlinegdb.com/9JIX9_8tf](https://onlinegdb.com/9JIX9_8tf)

Comment: You are fantastic, Richard! Thank you very much for the help and quick answers! I've tested your script on thousands of my actual files. It works like a charm. Very fast.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to unindent everything from `P1=[]` to `D=np.array(D1)` one level. Nothing in that block is using either `num` or `line` from the previous enumeration.

```
import os
import csv
import numpy as np
data=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Path/to/file"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            lines = open(os.path.join(root,file)).readlines()
            strings=open(os.path.join(root,file)).read()
            for num, line in enumerate(lines):
                Name=lines[1]
                if "Text1" in line:
                    num_line_min=int(num+5)
                if "Text2" in line:
                    num_line_max=int(num-3)
            # unindent start
            P1=[]
            D1=[]
            for i in range(num_line_min,num_line_max):
                L1_2=lines[i]
                L1_1=L1_2.split()
                L2=float(L1_1[0])
                D2=float(L1_1[1])
                P1.append(L2)
                D1.append(D2)
            P=np.array(P1)
            D=np.array(D1)
            # unindent end

            datal=[Name,P,D]
            data.append(datal)
with open("Test.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Though as @blhsing points out in a comment, hardcoding the offsets of 3 and 5 seems incorrect as well.

This isn't the cleanest algorithm, but this should get the correct positions, although I get a range of `range(9, 19)` for the provided sample.

```
count_min_offset = False
min_offset = 0
reading_data = False
count_max_offset = False
max_offset = 0

for num, line in enumerate(lines):
    if num == 0:
        Name = line
    elif "Text1" in line:
        num_line_min=num
        count_min_offset = True
    elif count_min_offset == True:
        min_offset += 1
        if line.strip():  # Need to strip the '\n'
            count_min_offset = False
            reading_data = True
    elif reading_data:
        if not line.strip():  # Need to strip the '\n'
            reading_data = False
            count_max_offset = True
    elif count_max_offset:
        max_offset += 1
        if "Text2" in line:
            num_line_max = num
            break
```

Comment: Thank you. What you suggested works, but "Name" does not appear in the csv file. Do you have an idea how to extract "Name" as well? The lines I'm interested in in my text files are always +5 and -3 lines away from "Text1" and "Text2", respectively, but thank you for suggesting how to avoid the hardcoding. I will use that when needed in the future.

Comment: Is "Name" the literal string "Name", any text that appears before "Text1", or something that's always in the first line

Comment: I think my solution the line `Name = lines[1]` should be moved to be before the for loop, and it should probably be `Name = lines[0]`?

Comment: "Name" is a string. I need to extract only a part of that string, and I know how to do that once the entire string is extracted. It does not appear in the first line of the actual files. Thank you for your time and contribution. Richard provided an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems. But first your code will miss the last entry in your example: `(9, 25)`.

Then you don't actually need `numpy.array` here, you can just use plain Python `list`.

Your data contains integers, not fractions, since there are no decimal points, Python integers are unbounded, while floats have a maximum upper limit and cannot represent large integers as is, use `int` instead of `float` to correctly represent integers, and you will also get rid of `.0`s.

That said, you want the output to be like this: `['Name', (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (5, 10, 8, 9, 12, 16, 11, 17, 15, 25)]`. What is the rationale behind this? Why not use something like this: `['Name', [(0, 5), (1, 10), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 12), (5, 16), (6, 11), (7, 17), (8, 15), (9, 25)]]` that is the format you get?

My code below will give you the second format, if you really want to change the format for whatever reason, use `p, d = zip(*data)`.

Then .csv is probably not a suitable format for your data, consider using .json.

Your example data would produce the following JSON:

```
{
    "Name": [
        [0, 5],
        [1, 10],
        [2, 8],
        [3, 9],
        [4, 12],
        [5, 16],
        [6, 11],
        [7, 17],
        [8, 15],
        [9, 25]
    ]
}
```

And you can use a simple recursive function to get all text files inside a folder and its sub-folders:

```
import os

def get_text_files(path):
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith('.txt'):
            yield entry.path
        elif entry.is_dir():
            yield from get_text_files(entry)
```

Then we can use a single loop to get all data from the lines, we can loop through the lines and check if the current line is `'Text1'`, if it is, we can just skip the current iteration, and from the next iteration on, we get the numbers from the current line if it is not empty, and then when we hit `'Text2'` we are done, we can break the loop:

```
data = []
started = False
for line in lines:
    if "Name" in line:
        name = line.strip()
    if "Text1" in line:
        started = True
        continue
    if "Text2" in line:
        break
    if started and (line := line.strip()):
        a, b = map(int, line.split())
        data.append((a, b))
```

Putting it all together:

```
import os
import json

def get_text_files(path):
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith('.txt'):
            yield entry.path
        elif entry.is_dir():
            yield from get_text_files(entry)

data = {}
for file in get_text_files('path/to/folder'):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    started = False
    col1, col2 = [], []
    for line in lines:
        if "Name" in line:
            name = line.strip()
        if "Text1" in line:
            started = True
            continue
        if "Text2" in line:
            break
        if started and (line := line.strip()):
            a, b = map(float, line.split())
            col1.append(a); col2.append(b)
    data[name] = {'col1': a, 'col2': b}

with open('path/to/outputfile', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, fp=f, indent=4)
```

---

***Edit***

I have made the numbers `float` as OP requested, and separated the pairs into two columns. But it is impossible to make `numpy.array` serialized as is (that is when deserialized the object will be `numpy.array`) to either csv or json, you need to convert it back by calling `numpy.array` to explicitly cast to array when loading the data. (Or you can use pickle but it isn't cross version and unsafe if from other sources)

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. It should have been num_line_max+1 in the range. The provided text file and the scripts are simplified examples. In my actual files, the numbers are floats, so I need them. The arrays are needed because I will do mathematical operations with the extracted numbers. The actual output file will show a number calculated from the array values and not show the arrays themselves. Again, this is just a simplified example. If I can extract the numbers as needed, I can do with them whatever is needed.

Answer (score 0):

File objects maintain a file pointer that does not reset when new iterators are created. If a for loop doesn't consume the full file, anther loop can resume where it left off. Instead of reading the whole file and trying to maintain indexes to the parts you want, you can implement a series of scans instead.

You can pull the processing of a single file into a function - which is good for readability and generally to separate the different tasks of your program. Have it scan for "Name", then "Text1". It can then read and process data until it sees "Text2". No need for enumeration or keeping track of indexes.

Then write a separate loop to process the files. `os.walk` works well, but you can use `glob` to do a bit more of the work for you.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from glob import glob
import os

def txt_file_to_arrays(filename):
    """Converts ???? type files to numpy arrays, each holding one of the
    pair of floats listed within the section between "Text1" and "Text2".

    returns: (Name, np.array(first value), np.array(second value))
    """
    Name = "<NO NAME>"
    P1 = []
    D1 = []
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if "Name" in line:
                Name = line.split()[0]
                break
        for line in infile:
            if "Text1" in line:
                break
        for line in infile:
            if "Text2" in line:
                break
            if line.strip():
                values = [float(val) for val in line.split()[:2]]
                P1.append(values[0])
                D1.append(values[1])
    return Name, np.array(P1), np.array(D1)

file_spec = r"Path/to/file/**/*.txt"
file_spec = r"./**/*.txt"
data = []
# glob is like os.walk but does the extension check for you
for filename in glob(file_spec, recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        data.append(txt_file_to_arrays(filename))

with open("Test.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

That outer loop could be slimmed down to

```
with open("Test.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(txt_file_to_arrays(filename)
            for filename in glob(file_spec, recursive=True))
```